# sql trigger error:invalid specification

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

i am creating a trigger and receiving some error, which i m not able to understand. Pls can anyone help me with that.

```
create or REPLACE TRIGGER trig_data
  BEFORE INSERT
    ON data_db REFERENCING OLD AS OLD AND NEW AS NEW
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      SELECT RAHUL_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.USERID FROM DUAL; 
    END;
Error report:
ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification
04079. 00000 -  "invalid trigger specification"
*Cause:    The create TRIGGER statement is invalid.
*Action:   Check the statement for correct syntax.
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this appears to be an oracle trigger.  Will you please remove the sql-server tag from the question?

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong:

```
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD AND NEW AS NEW
```

There should be no "AND" there:

```
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
```

(In fact why not just remove it altogether as it does nothing?)